# AJAX load in same page causes divs to repeat

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm performing the ajax call to the same page which works perfectly however it reload existing divs. I was wondering if there was a way to suppress it? Here's more details:

### My project setup

**index.php - Open records Controller**

```
/**app logic**/

view('open',$data); //require '../views/layout.php';
```

**layout.php**

```
/*all the js scripts and stylesheets loaded here*/

<div id='logo'></div>
<div id='nav'></div>

include($path); //loads the open.view.php file
```

**open.view.php**

```
/*AJAX call to self*/


function getViaAjax(chosenGroup){
    $.post('index.php',{group:chosenGroup},
                function(data)
                {   
                    $("#default").remove();
                    $('#group-tickets').html(data);
                });
}
```

As you might be able to tell, this causes the `#logo` and `#nav` div to duplicate on the page. I understand that I can do a AJAX post to a different file and I will get around the issue altogether but I was wondering if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Documentation Explains : `The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.`

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Comment: Thanks.It works but..it seems to break everything else. Anyway,I'll accept your answer on the merit of pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to reopen the question in the event there are some alternative answers.